# Copy data from one worksheet to another without formatting and also use a cell to organize the copy

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

So I am working on a excel sheet that saves scores from a test into historical data on another sheet. I found a macro online that works I just want to add to it.

The current code:

```
Sub SaveScores()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim iRow As Integer

    Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("SourceData")
    iRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & iRow)
    rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngTarget

End Sub
```

Now this code works fine for the purpose that the site explained. To copy from one worksheet to another to the first un-used cell.

What I am trying to add is the following two features:

1. Make a cell above the data that provides something like Test conducted on: 10-Oct-20
2. Remove data that does not have information in the C column, prior to copying the data.

This is my first time using VBA within an excel document so I am unsure if this should be made all within SaveScores() or if I should make multiple macros and then run them on the button press.

Cheers!

Comment: I'd recommend you create different subroutines for specific tasks. How you organize those (i.e. where you put them in you project) is up to you. In your case I'd all put them in the same module (i.e., the file where your `SaveScores` subroutine is).

Think of it as a recipe. It consists of steps. The main recipe just lists the steps in order, the steps are your subroutines. You make one subroutine do one thing (Single Responsiblity Principle), so they can be easily swapped out if neccesary. So in your case, you would have a 3-step recipe.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you [edit] your post and add some sample data of what you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok so that makes a bit more sense. I’ll edit in some data when i get back into work tomorrow. 

With adding subroutines can multiple be added to the same button? And if they can do they follow any order?

Comment: Not sure if you're just pulling our legs, but yes of course you can. A button click can be mapped to any routine, including one that says 'do this, then that, etc.'